# capture the pixels of the screen in an array

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am trying to capture the pixels from the screen to an array and then work with it somehow. I have made this short program just to see if the capturing works, but it seems it doesn't. I saw a lot of examples of this on the internet, but it is always the same as the code I have. Maybe I am missing some little mistake. Could someone help me please?

PS: It looks like the picture in the array was somehow shifted or flipped, because I can see right colors but on wrong place. (In the code, the Y coordinate is flipped, because I found that it should be like that, but it doesn't work without the flipping anyway)

```
void ScreenCap(BYTE*& pScreenData, int& iScreenX, int& iScreenY)
{
    iScreenX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    iScreenY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
    HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
    HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, iScreenX, iScreenY);
    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);

    BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, iScreenX, iScreenY, hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = iScreenX;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = iScreenY;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    pScreenData = new BYTE[4 * iScreenX * iScreenY];

    GetDIBits(
        hCaptureDC,
        hCaptureBitmap,
        0,
        iScreenY,
        pScreenData,
        &bmi,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS
    );

    ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);
    DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
    DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
}
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        BYTE* pScreenData = 0;
        int iScreenX, iScreenY;
        ScreenCap(pScreenData, iScreenX, iScreenY);

        std::cout << "Captured screenshot of size: " << iScreenX << " " << iScreenY << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);

        while (true)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
            {
                while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE));
                break;
            }
            POINT pCursor;
            GetCursorPos(&pCursor);
            const int r = pScreenData[4 * ((iScreenY - pCursor.y - 1) * iScreenX + pCursor.x) + 2]; 
            const int g = pScreenData[4 * ((iScreenY - pCursor.y - 1) * iScreenX + pCursor.x) + 1];
            const int b = pScreenData[4 * ((iScreenY - pCursor.y - 1) * iScreenX + pCursor.x) + 0];
            const int a = pScreenData[4 * ((iScreenY - pCursor.y - 1) * iScreenX + pCursor.x) + 3];
            std::cout << pCursor.x << " " << pCursor.y << ": " << r << " " << g << " " << b << " " << a << std::endl;
            Sleep(200);
        }

        delete[] pScreenData;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not related, but holy `<Windows.h>`. I've been using SFML for C++ a while now, and getting a screenshot there can be done in 2 lines. I am just shocked by this mess - and it also only runs on one operating system (windows). mhpf.

Comment: You want help with what? change to `bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -iScreenY;` if you don't want the y-coordinate get flipped.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani The problem is, that the picture in the array doesnt match the real picture on the screen. But when I move my mouse over the screen, I see the colors that are on the screen but on another place. Thanks for your advice, but as I wrote, the picture is wrong both if I do flip the y coordinate or if I don't.

Comment: Maybe your application is not DPI aware. Call `SetProcessDPIAware()` for quick fix. Use `GetPixel` to check individual pixels. Otherwise save the bits to a bitmap file or something, it makes testing easier.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Oh, thanks a lot! it is working now with the SetProcessDPIAware(). I would have probably never come of it myself. Can I accept this as a solution somehow?

Comment: You are welcome. It looks like a duplicate.